# PySide Error - QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted

Tags: python, pyside

I'm baffled by this one. I tried moving the `QPainter` to it's own `def` as some have suggested, but it gives the exact same error. Here's the `def` I created.

```
def PaintButtons(self):
    solid = QtGui.QPixmap(200, 32)
    paint = QtGui.QPainter()
    paint.begin(solid)
    paint.setPen(QtGui.Qcolor(255,255,255))
    paint.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
    paint.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 32)
    paint.end()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just a typo. You're using `Qcolor` (the first occurrence).
Changing that to `QColor` will do the trick. :)